# CGContext.init returns nil

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm making a simple graphics app with moving objects and some animation for Mac OS.

What I'm trying to do is to create a bitmap in memory which is to be rendered to the actual context at the end of a frame (not sure whether CG is a proper way to do this):

```
let tempBitmap = CGContext.init (data: nil, width: width, 
    height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),  
    bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
```

but it always returns `nil`.

What is the proper way to create an in-memory bitmap?

Answer (score 6):

Your combination is not supported. You can't have RGB color with no alpha. The list of supported pixel formats is in the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB).

You can ignore the alpha ("none skip first" or "none skip last") but you can't work directly on 24-bit (3x8) packed pixels.

Comment: @Elagoff https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work